# Sphinx apidoc section titles for Python module/package names

Tags: python, html, title, python-sphinx, api-doc

When I run `sphinx-apidoc` and then `make html` it produces doc pages that have "Subpackages" and "Submodules" sections and "module" and "package" at the end of each module/package name in the table of contents (TOC). How might I prevent these extra titles from being written without editing the Sphinx source?

here's an example doc pages I would like to make (notice TOC):

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html#documentation

I understand it is due to the apidoc.py file in the sphinx source (line 88):

https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/ef3092d458cc00c4b74dd342ea05ba1059a5da70/sphinx/apidoc.py?at=default

I could manually edit each individual .rst file to delete these titles or just remove those lines of code from the script but then I'd have to compile the Sphinx source code. Is there an automatic way of doing this without manually editing the Sphinx source?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29385564/407651.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was struggling with this myself when I found this question... The answers given didn't quite do what I wanted so I vowed to come back when I figured it out. :)

---

In order to remove 'package' and 'module' from the auto-generated headings and have docs that are *truly* automatic, you need to make changes in several places so bear with me.

First, you need to handle your `sphinx-apidoc` options. What I use is:

```bash
sphinx-apidoc -fMeET ../yourpackage -o api
```

Assuming you are running this from inside the `docs` directory, this will source `yourpackage` for documentation and put the resulting files at `docs/api`. The options I'm using here will overwrite existing files, put module docs before submodule docs, put documentation for each module on its own page, abstain from creating module/package headings if your docstrings already have them, and it won't create a table of contents file.

That's a lot of options to remember, so I just add this to the end of my `Makefile`:

```
buildapi:
    sphinx-apidoc -fMeET ../yourpackage -o api
    @echo "Auto-generation of API documentation finished. " \
          "The generated files are in 'api/'"
```

With this in place, you can just run `make buildapi` to build your docs.

Next, create an `api.rst` file at the root of your docs with the following contents:

```
API Documentation
=================

Information on specific functions, classes, and methods.

.. toctree::
   :glob:

   api/*
```

This will create a table of contents with everything in the `api` folder.

Unfortunately, `sphinx-apidoc` will still generate a `yourpackage.rst` file with an ugly 'yourpackage package' heading, so we need one final piece of configuration. In your `conf.py` file, find the `exclude_patterns` option and add this file to the list. It should look something like this:

```python
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'api/yourpackage.rst']
```

Now your documentation should look exactly like you designed it in the module docstrings, and you never have to worry about your Sphinx docs and your in-code documentation being out of sync!

Comment: to me this accomplished nothing near what the OP wanted. you just changed the TOC, but the internal docs are the same because the generated .rst have those titles by default

Comment: I'm directing `sphinx-apidoc` to not create the headings by default with the `-E` option. With this option enabled, if your module has a proper docstring header, Sphinx will use that instead of generating one.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice the difference because the packages didn't have docstrings, so the headings were still there, but even modules without docstrings had no headers in the .rst files.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to remove Subpackage and Submodule as well? Then using the name og subpackages and submodules instead.

Comment: @JenGarcia ...  if your module has a proper docstring header. How do you set that? Couldn't find anything about it anywhere.

Comment: Once you get into more complex structures, the fix involves text replacement like @Jakob suggested in their answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably late, but the options `maxdepth` or `titlesonly` should do the trick.

More details :
http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/markup/toctree.html

Comment: I have the same problem as @ecoe , and I have tried `:maxdepth: 2` and `:titlesonly:` in my `index.rst` toctree, and I still get those headings. The problem is that `sphinx-apidoc` puts these headings into the generated `.rst` files. Any idea on how to work around them?

Like @ocoe says, one can always edit them away from the `.rst`, but then you lose the whole point of letting `sphinx-apidoc` generate these files for you, as you would have to edit/post-process them each time :(

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by Jen Garcia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35250460/373710) helped a lot but it requires to put repeat package names in docstrings. I used a Perl one-liner to remove the "module" or "package" suffix in my Makefile:

```
docs:
    rm -rf docs/api docs/_build
    sphinx-apidoc -MeT -o docs/api wdmapper
    for f in docs/api/*.rst; do\
        perl -pi -e 's/(module|package)$$// if $$. == 1' $$f ;\
    done
    $(MAKE) -C docs html
```

Comment: Do you have a similar fix for make.bat ?

Comment: @mr.bjerre sorry I don't develop under Windows. The perl code could be replaced by a little python script that does the same, but I am happy with the current solution under Unix.

Comment: I get a syntax error when using the perl script:
`syntax error at -e line 1, near ". =="
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
`

Comment: @Eddy what OS and Perl version do you use? Looks like you missed a `$` (?)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to use the titles within my docstrings as I was following numpy style guidelines. So I first generate the rst files and then run the following python script as a post-processing step.

```py
from pathlib import Path


src_dir = Path("source/api")
for file in src_dir.iterdir():
    print("Processed RST file:", file)
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        lines = f.read()

    junk_strs = ["Submodules\n----------", "Subpackages\n-----------"]

    for junk in junk_strs:
        lines = lines.replace(junk, "")

    lines = lines.replace(" module\n=", "\n")

    with open(file, "w") as f:
        f.write(lines)
```

This script is kept in the same directory as the makefile. I also add the following lines to the makefile.

```
html:
    # rm -r "$(BUILDDIR)"
    python rst_process.py
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M $@ "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)
```

Now running `make html` builds the documentation in the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm 100% answering your question, but I had a similar experience and I realized I was running `sphinx-apidoc` with the `-f` flag each time, which created the `.rst` files fresh each time.

Now I'm allowing `sphinx-apidoc` to generate the `.rst` files once, but not overwriting them, so I can modify them to change titles/etc. and then run `make html` to propagate the changes. If I want to freshly generate `.rst` files I can just remove the files I want to regenerate or pass the `-f` flag in.

So you do have to change the rst files but only once.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Apidoc, you can use a custom Jinja template to control the generated output.

The default templates are here: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/5.x/sphinx/templates/apidoc

You can make a local copy of each template using the same names (e.g. `source/_templates/toc.rst_t`) and invoke `sphinx-apidoc` with the `--templatedir` option (e.g. `sphinx-apidoc --templatedir source/_templates`).

Once you are using your own template file, you can customize it however you want. For example, you can remove the ugly "package" and "module" suffix, which is added at this stage.