# How does 'autodoc_default_flags' work in python Sphinx configuration?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, numpydoc, sphinx-napoleon

I am trying to generate documentation for my python classes using Sphinx 1.4 and `sphinx-apidoc` and the `sphinx.ext.autodoc` extension.

I have a lot of modules and I want each to only show class names, but not the full list of methods in the class (which all have docstrings in my code).

Here is a snippet of my `conf.py` file:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/blah/sphinx/src')

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']
autodoc_member_order = 'bysource'
autodoc_default_flags = ['no-members']
```

Here is a toy module (`my_module.py`) that I'm using to figure out how Sphinx works:

```
"""
==============
Test my module
==============
"""

def module_function():
    """Here is a module function, let's see if it's in"""
     print 'module level'

class TestClass:
    """
    Test this class

    Here is some more class documentation.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """Here is init"""
        self.test = True

    def getName(self, inputName):
        """Summary for getName

        more documentation for getName
        """    
        print "hello"
        return inputName
```

I'm only showing the code for this class in case there's something I need to be doing in the doc-strings that I'm missing.

I run sphinx-apidoc to generate the rst files:

**sphinx-apidoc -f -M -e -o docs/ /blah/sphinx/src/**

then build:

**make html**

I might not be clear about what `autodoc_default_flags` should be doing. I thought that when you ran sphinx-apidoc with those flags set, then those flags were applied to the directives in the .rst files. However, after I run sphinx-apidoc, I get this .rst file:

```
my_module module
=====================

.. automodule:: my_module
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

I wouldn't have expected `:members:` to be applied due to setting those flags, but there it is! And the html page has the methods fully there along with their docstrings.

FWIW, `autodoc_member_order` is working; I can set it to switch the order the methods appear.

So my questions:

1. Is `autodoc_default_flags` supposed to do what I described or am I misunderstanding it?
2. If it can be used to automatically hide members from the build, am I using it correctly? If so, any thoughts about why I'm still getting `:members:` added to the .rst files?
3. If I'm misunderstanding it, then what does it really do? And how can I hide the method docstring from my build automatically?

Ideally I want something like SciPy has, for example here:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html

For that I'm playing around with Napoleon and the sphinx.ext.autosummary extensions, but it seems like apidoc alone should be able to hide class method documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *I thought that when you ran sphinx-apidoc with those flags set, then those flags were applied to the directives in the .rst files.*

[**sphinx-build**](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html) does apply `autodoc_default_flags` in conf.py, unless the flags are overridden in *.rst files.

[**sphinx-apidoc**](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) does not use conf.py.

---

It is possible to customize the flags in the *.rst files generated by **sphinx-apidoc** via the [`SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#envvar-SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS) environment variable. Example:

```
$ export SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS=no-members
$ sphinx-apidoc -o docs/ /blah/sphinx/src/
```

This will result in `automodule` directives that look like this:

```
.. automodule:: my_module
   :no-members:
```

If you need more control over the generated output, you could perhaps write your own version of the apidoc.py module. See [Customize templates for `sphinx-apidoc`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29385564/407651).

Comment: That worked and is exactly what I wanted! Yup, would have been nice to know about the SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS variable. I'll be looking into templates next. I was banging my head against this for a couple days, so great to get such an easy answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks for the tip - sadly this does not cover ``automodule`` directives with arguments - https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4057

Comment: Thanks! Why doesn't the sphinx documentation have a example?