# How to insert class diagram to sphinx-apidoc automatically w/o loss of chasing latest code

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want to generate the documentation of my Python program.

When I generate the documentation, I always execute `sphinx-apidoc` to chase the latest code and then execute `make html`.

```
$ sphinx-apidoc -f -o doc .
$ make -C doc html
```

I use `sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram` to generate class diagram. It is possible to generate class diagram if the following text is inserted to .rst file **manually**.

```
.. inheritance-diagram:: mymodule.MyClass1 mymodule.MyClass2
    :parts: 1
```

However the above text is erased by `sphinx-apidoc -f`. I want to know how to insert class diagram to sphinx-apidoc **automatically** w/o loss of chasing latest code.

If possible, I want to specify where the class diagrams are inserted (e.g., before for each `.. automodule::` or any other nice approaches).

My Environment:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
$ pip3 --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
$ pip3 freeze | grep Sphinx
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Sphinx==1.5.2
```

Comment: You will have to create your own version of sphinx-apidoc for this. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/29385564/407651.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll try to modify sphinx-apidoc itself.