# How to avoid duplicated function docs with sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Assume I have the following structure

```
mypackage
    __init__.py
    core.py
```

With `__init__.py`:

```
from .core import my_function

__all__ = ['my_function']
```

And `core.py`

```
def myfunction():
    ''' really cool function '''
    pass
```

Running `sphinx-apidoc --full  -o docs` and `python setup.py build_sphinx`
I get the documentation of `myfunction` twice.

How can I avoid this duplication, preferably with having the documentation only at the toplevel (as this is the API intended for the users).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385564/customize-templates-for-sphinx-apidoc