# Remove the word "module" from Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Using [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) for documenting my Python project. I want to **remove the word "module"** which follows the name of each python file (in the navbar, TOC, the page title, etc).

**e.g. Details:**

The project is composed of 2 files `utils.py` and `main.py`.

In my `index.rst` file, I use:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   utils
   main
```

to import both files as "modules". From the `docs/` folder, I then call:

```
sphinx-apidoc -f -o ./source/ .. 
make html
```

to generate the static site. In the site, the word "module" follows every file name, and I would like to remove it.

Comment: After `sphinx-apidoc -f -o ./source/ ..`, what is in your `utils.rst` and `main.rst`? I think part of the problem is that [sphinx-apidoc is designed for packages](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#description), not modules: "sphinx-apidoc is a tool for automatic generation of Sphinx sources that, using the autodoc extension, **document a whole package** in the style of other automatic API documentation tools."

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29385564/407651

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sphinx 2.2 adds templating for the reST files generated by `sphinx-apidoc`.

Use the `--templatedir` option to set the path to a dir containing `module.rst_t`, `package.rst_t` and `toc.rst_t` files. The files can be created from the corresponding files in `site-packages/sphinx/templates/apidoc`.

Then, in `package.rst_t`replace

```
{{- [submodule, "module"] | join(" ") | e | heading(2) }}
```

with

```
{{- submodule | e | heading(2) }}
```

Repeat for `module.rst_t`.

Comment: According to https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/changes.html#id9, the `--templatedir` option was added already in Sphinx 2.2.0.

Comment: @mzjn True, but as far as I could tell, that version wasn't released (not available via PyPI / pip).

Comment: Strange that it does not work for you. I was able to install it via pip. And https://pypi.org/project/Sphinx/ says that 2.2.0 is the latest release.

Comment: Ah -- it was released on Aug 18. I posted this answer on the 16th :)

Comment: I can't find the default files in `site-packages/sphinx/templates/apidoc` on my computer, but you can find them [here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/master/sphinx/templates/apidoc)

Comment: I expected the `toc.rst_t` template to be used to generate `modules.rst` (based on the packaged templates) but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution uses JS to find & replace the word "module" *after* the page loads:

Create a file `source/_templates/layout.html` with the following content:

```html
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/ module/g, '');
  }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Make sure that `conf.py` has `templates_path = ['_templates']` set, then Sphinx will append the script to the `<head>` of all documentation pages, and voila!