# How to force sphinx to only use filename as heading in a multi-level project?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, sphinx-apidoc

I have a sample project:

```
docs/
src/
----| model/
------------| first.py
------------| second.py
----| utils
------------| some_helper.py
------------| some_organizer.py
----| io
------------| read_data.py
------------| dataset/
---------------------| lazy_dataset.py
---------------------| in_mem_dataset.py
```

When I use `sphinx-apidoc` it generates very ugly headings like this: `src.some_package.some_subpackge.some_module`. What I want to do is that do not repeat the previous headings in the generated ToC.
Something like this is generated:

```
src.some_package
   - src.some_package.some_subpackage
          - src.some_package.some_subpackage.some_module
```

Something like this is my preference:

```
some_package
   - some_subpackage
          - some_module
```

I have tried generating api-doc using the way described [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003122/sphinx-apidoc-section-titles-for-python-module-package-names) but I had no luck.

Currently I generate sphinx project using: `sphinx-quickstart` and then append this to the makefile:

```
buildapi:
    sphinx-apidoc -fMeET ../src -o api
    @echo "Auto-generation of api documentation finished. " \
          "The generated files are in 'api/'"
```

and insert an `api.rst` in `docs/` folder. The content of that file is:

```
API Documentation
=================

Information on specific functions, classes, and methods.

.. toctree::
   :glob:

   api/*
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57520238/407651

Comment: @mzjn now it actually does not. Isn't there any other elegant solution?